# /bin/sh: Syntax Error: end of file unexpected

Tags: linux, makefile

I am getting an error when running the following makefile with `make -f makefile2 install` (apart install the rest is working):

```
all:myapp

#which compiler
CC = gcc

#Where to install
INSTDIR = /usr/local/bin

#where are include files kept
INCLUDE = .

#Options for development
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -ansi

#Options for release
# CFLAGS = -O -Wall -ansi

myapp: main.o 2.o 3.o
    $(CC) -o myapp main.o 2.o 3.o

main.o: main.c a.h
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

2.o: 2.c a.h b.h
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c 2.c

3.o: 3.c b.h c.h
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c 3.c         

clean:
    -rm main.o 2.o 3.o

install: myapp
    @if [ -d $(INSTDIR) ]; \
      then \
      cp myapp $(INSTDIR);\
      chmod a+x $(INSTDIR)/myapp;\
      chmod og-w $(INSTDIR)/myapp;\
      echo "Installed in $(INSTDIR)";\
    else
      echo "Sorry, $(INSTDIR) does not exist";\
    fi
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error /bin/sh: 7: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

From what I understand it is a white space/tabulation/non unix character problem in the last lines of the makefile (after install:). But even trying to delete all spaces and replacing with tabulation I didn't manage to run the makefile properly. The code comes directly from a programming book I'm reading and is an example. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why not `[ -d $(INSTDIR) ] || mkdir -p $(INSTDIR}`?  Most users would expect that behavior.

Comment: Well, the code is only illustrating explanations about using shell in a makefile from the programming book, they probably just wanted to show this syntax, but thank you for the piece of advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing a trailing slash on your else under the install rule. It should be:

```
install: myapp
    @if [ -d $(INSTDIR) ]; \
      then \
      cp myapp $(INSTDIR);\
      chmod a+x $(INSTDIR)/myapp;\
      chmod og-w $(INSTDIR)/myapp;\
      echo "Installed in $(INSTDIR)";\
    else\
      echo "Sorry, $(INSTDIR) does not exist";\
    fi
```